# Cast Object to Array - IllegalArgumentException - Argument is not an array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

i have an issue with casting and conversion,

**messages** list is of **Object** class, each element of the list is an array of different types, so i need a way that will help me cast each element in the object component into array.

This is my portion of code.

```
    String query = "SELECT m.MSG_CODE, m.MSG_TYPE, m.MSG_TITLE, m.MSG_CORE, me.IS_READ "
            + "FROM EBANKING.EBAN_MESSAGING m, EBANKING.EBAN_MESSAGING_ENDUSER me WHERE me.END_USER_CODE = "
            + userCode + " AND me.MSG_CODE = m.MSG_CODE";
    List<Object> messages = ebankingPersistenceService.getResultNativeQuery(query);
    List<EbanMessagingDto> notifications = new ArrayList<EbanMessagingDto>();

    for (Object e : messages.toArray()) {
        System.out.println(Array.getLength(e)+" ---------------- IS THE LENGTH");
        System.out.println(Array.getLong(e, 0)+" ---------------- IS THE FIRST ELEMENT");
    }
```

The last line causes always the **IllegalArgumentException : Argument is not an array** Yet it shows the length as 5 in the previous line.

Any help will be infinitely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

See guys, **e** is an array. I have no idea what the going on.

Comment: Can you show us the output as well please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to cast the "**e**" object to table :

```
    for (Object e : messages) {
    Object[] data = (Object[]) e;
    System.out.println(Array.getLength(e)+" ---------------- IS THE LENGTH");
    System.out.println(data[0]+" ---------------- IS THE FIRST ELEMENT");
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i was totally misguided.

Answer (score 3):

<del>`messages.toArray()` will give you `Object[]` and with your loop your traversing the `Object[]` array with a single object i.e `e` and later your are passing a single object to `Array.getLength(e)` and to `Array.getLong(e, 0)`.</del>

**Update** : the exception is thrown if the value at given index is can't converted to the return type i.e `long` and in this case it is `BidDecimal` can't be converted to `long` so hence exception , 
so as an alternative you can use `get` method which will `return` an `Object`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah Mr.Delimanolis but there can be lot of possibilities but as you can see the full code is not there about what this `ebankingPersistenceService.getResultNativeQuery(query)` returns but if you connect the dots , the two function with Array class need an array but they didn't get hence exception

Comment: the **ebankingPersistenceService.getResultNativeQuery(query)** returns a List<Object>.

Comment: @SoufianeRabii the Object can hold anything and in this case the `Array` class is unable to convert your `e` input to long so you can use the alternative i.e `get` function

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yup that was an array and it is clear now due to the error pic , the object was bigDecimal which can't be convert to long so i suggested the alternative solution , thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Really this error mean "argument is not array **of numbers**". Ie if you pass String[] for example:

```
String[] test = {"123", "124"};
Array.getLong(test, 0);
```

so, if getLenght(x) returns 5, but getLong(x,0) failed, then x is array, but x[0] can't be converted to long

Answer (score -2):

`Array.getLong(e, 0)` here it is expecting e to be an array but you are passing an object.. kindly convert it first and then use it...

Another [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080288/reflection-of-an-array-in-java) which i found helpful.. its not the same problem as you but something similar.. it might help you and gain more knowledge

Comment: How do you explain that `getLong` throws an exception, but `getLength` does not, for the same argument?

Comment: Why is it showing the length then if it's not an Array

Comment: @SoufianeRabii kindly paste the complete code and the output for the same.. you posting the output will help us a lot in solving this issue

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis then what is your solution for this? I will answer to your question once Soufiane posts her output as well